# Google Earth Engine - Chart APP

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, chart

I made a script that makes a chart of the NDVI values by dates for different sites.
When I create an APP to share that chart, the only thing visualized is the MAP.

How do I create an APP with only (if possible) a Chart?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a chart beside, or entirely replacing, the map.

Beside can be demonstrated by [the demo script called "Two Chart Inspector"](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=Examples%3AUser%20Interface%2FTwo%20Chart%20Inspector) among others.

Or since you want *only* a chart, here's a really simple example of just that:

```
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
    .filterDate('2016-06-01', '2017-06-01');
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series(l8.select('B\\d'), ee.Geometry.Point(-21.81, 77.117))
    .setOptions({width: 800, height: 300});
ui.root.clear();
ui.root.add(chart);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created an NDVI chart app

https://harelg25.users.earthengine.app/view/ndvi-chart

here is the script

https://code.earthengine.google.com/96e79a56b94549f99a68edac999dbfea

Harel